# Simple currying in scala

Tags: scala, currying

I have the following two functions, written in scala:

```
def f: (Int,Int) => Int = (x,y) => x+y
def g: Int=>Int=>Int=x=>y=>x+y
```

Now I want to write a function that curries the function f, taking one argument, into a function g, taking two arguments.

Beside the definition I cant find a solution to this problem

```
curry: ((Int, Int) => Int) => (Int => Int => Int):
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> def f(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
f: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> def curry(fn: (Int, Int) => Int) = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => fn(x, y)
curry: (fn: (Int, Int) => Int)Int => (Int => Int)

scala> val g = curry(f)
g: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala> g(3)(4)
res0: Int = 7
```

Comment: Tht is, what I was looking for. Thanks. Can you answer one more question? If I enter `curry(f(2,3))` I get a Typemismatch. What did I understand wrongly?

Comment: Well, `f(2,3)` evaluates to `5`, an `Int`. `curry()` expects a function as its parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to still do a huge pile of work until I fully understand currying (currently trying to write an uncurry function), but that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Can you simply use the `curried` function?

```
scala> def f: (Int,Int) => Int = (x,y) => x+y
f: (Int, Int) => Int

scala> val g = f.curried
g: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala> g(1)(2)
res0: Int = 3
```

Edit: an example of a `curry` function based on the source code of `curried` in `Function2`:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C): A => B => C = (x1: A) => (x2: B) => f(x1,x2)
```

Comment: Is there any way of writing this as a function? Im trying to understand how to apply currying in Scala. I feel like I understand currying itself, but Im unable to apply it.

Comment: You can look at the source code of `curried` in `Function2`, it is pretty trivial. See the edit of my response.

Comment: Cool! Can you add a link to the source code? Perhaps it will drive someone to dive into it!